# Balance weight of a php script between apache and os

Tags: php, task

I wanted to balance a massive process on a web app by letting it to run on the OS instead of Apache. I could do it by shell executing the process but, i think better to get others opinion as well in this situation. Here is the scenario;

1. User log-in to the app
2. Click process
3. Continue processing on the server while letting the user to carry out his/her normal activities.
   Note: **User should not be Interrupted by the process, should be a parallel process.**

Answer (score 0):

Consider starting separate process on server that will be running continuously, will receive work units from PHP scripts, execute them and return results back.  PHP script and this process may use database to exchange work units, so when PHP have some work, it insert work description into the database.  When separate process is ready to work, it queries database for pending work units, marks them in database as being processed.  Later, then processing is done, it marks work unit in database as finished and attaches processing result to it.

Comment: Thanks Mik, but I need to figure out the whole architecture of the thing.